# SQL query: Copy all rows with Store_ID = 1

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, review

I have a table `review_store` with two columns: `review_id` and `store_id`
If I had to replace 1 with 2, I would do this:

```
UPDATE review_store 
SET store_id = '2' 
WHERE store_id = '1'
```

How do I copy/duplicate every row in which store_ID = 1 to Store_ID = 2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean create new records in the same table. Use [INSERT SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)

```
INSERT INTO review_store
SELECT review_id, '2' as Store_id
FROM review_store
WHERE Store_id = '1'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO review_store (review_id, store_id)
SELECT review_id, 2
FROM review_store 
WHERE store_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `review_store` SELECT 2, review_id FROM `review_store` WHERE store_id = 1
```

Note that if you have an id column, you should add a blank field for it, so

```
INSERT INTO `review_store` SELECT '', 2, review_id FROM `review_store` WHERE store_id = 1
```

Check the order of your fields, too. If review_id comes before store_id, you'll need to re-order the select.

Comment: VALUES and SELECT versions of INSERT to not combine; and not specifying target fields in the INSERT is very poor practice.